# How to fix a boolean method that returns true everytime asp.net

Tags: c#, sql-server, methods, sqlclient

I designed my webpage to read a data string then display the results on labels in an html table. I am attempting to highlight the row that my database reads as a current order. My only problem is only one record is set to be active but they all highlight as if they were active. I use an array to set my data and I also use the label to get the ID I need (all is in code below). I have posted my method and where I use it in the asp page load. How can I fix my method to return correctly?

The implementing of the method in page load

```
if (lineData.IsCurrentOrderFind(L68.Text))
{
    myTable.Rows[1].Cells[0].BgColor = "#FE2E2E";
    myTable.Rows[1].Cells[1].BgColor = "#FE2E2E";
    myTable.Rows[1].Cells[2].BgColor = "#FE2E2E";
    myTable.Rows[1].Cells[3].BgColor = "#FE2E2E";
    myTable.Rows[1].Cells[4].BgColor = "#FE2E2E";
}
```

Here is method that label above gets passed to

```
public bool IsCurrentOrderFind(string itemNumber)
    {

        StringBuilder sqlString = new StringBuilder();
        sqlString.Append("SELECT * ");
        sqlString.Append("FROM WorkOrder ");
        sqlString.Append("WHERE LineNumber = " + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Line"] + " AND LineCompleted =  0 AND (ScaleGroup LIKE '%1' OR ScaleGroup LIKE '%3') ");
        sqlString.Append(" AND CaseGenNum6 = @CaseGenNum6");

        SqlDataReader reader = null;
        SqlConnection dbConn = App_Code.DBHelper.getConnection();

        SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[] { new SqlParameter("@CaseGenNum6", itemNumber) };

        try
        {
            reader = App_Code.DBHelper.executeQuery(dbConn, sqlString.ToString(), parameters);
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                IsCurrentOrder = (reader["IsCurrentOrder"] != DBNull.Value && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader["IsCurrentOrder"].ToString())) ? true : false;
            }
            reader.Close();
            reader.Dispose();
            dbConn.Close();
            dbConn.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (dbConn != null)
            {
                try { dbConn.Close(); dbConn.Dispose(); }
                catch { }
            }
            if (reader != null)
            {
                try { reader.Close(); reader.Dispose(); }
                catch { }
            }
        }
        if (IsCurrentOrder == true) I realize this is not necessary
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use a `GridView` and a single query?

Comment: " ? true : false;" its unnecessary. you can write: `return reader["IsCurrentOrder"] != DBNull.Value && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader["IsCurrentOrder"].ToString()`

Comment: @TimSchmelter just the way they wanted it done.

Comment: They? Who are they? Here's a serious suggestion - real time debugging. Put a break point on that line where you assign IsCurrentOrder (within that while reader.read loop). Debug and see that occurs. That loop doesn't look right and the assignment line line is nasty (so much going on). Writing so much code on a single line can be clever if you are confident you know what you are doing. Writing it out "long hand" so you get the right result is much smarter.

Comment: The problem still exists?

Comment: @robnick have bedugged many times and it returns true even when false I'm wondering if the db allowing nulls is the problem.

Comment: I have never seen such thorough closing code before... Delete *all* of it and use `using`. Why are people in 2014 still not using `using`? Is it such an esoteric feature? It is the *standard*.

Comment: IsCurrentOrder is not declared locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem could be with this expression:

```
!string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader["IsCurrentOrder"].ToString())
```

Instead of calling `ToString()`, try simply casting it to a string:

```
!string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)reader["IsCurrentOrder"])
```

Possibly even better (the previous line might throw an exception if it's not really a string):

```
!string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader["IsCurrentOrder"] as string)
```

The reason being is that if the string is really null, calling `ToString()` will return a *non-null* string "null".

Comment: Inverse effect nothing was selected.

Comment: I appreciate the accept of my answer. Did you end up figuring out what the problem was? If so I can add that as well.

Comment: Yes I did the main problem was that I wasn't comparing the data in my table to what m reader was saying. aka if(a = b(reader.value))

Answer (score 1):

IsCurrentOrder is not declared locally.  It seems to be declared at a higher scope.  When you enter this function, nothing is initializing the variable (back to false). So, it is remaining at its last setting.  Try this code instead:

```
public bool IsCurrentOrderFind(string itemNumber)
{
    bool IsCurrentOrder = false;

    //and the rest of your source code
```

Answer (score 0):

the line

```
IsCurrentOrder = (reader["IsCurrentOrder"] != DBNull.Value && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader["IsCurrentOrder"].ToString())) ? true : false;
        }
```

It's not actually checking the value of the field, only that it's not null or empty.

Try

```
if(
(reader["IsCurrentOrder"] != DBNull.Value 
&& 
!string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader["IsCurrentOrder"].ToString())) 
)
{
    IsCurrentOrder = reader["IsCurrentOrder"];
}
else
IsCurrentOrder = false;
```

I think there is a lot of refactoring you could do to this method though that will simplify the logic.

Comment: `IsCurrentOrder = reader["IsCurrentOrder"];` you need cast object to bool, and unnecessary.